# Validating 2 things for TextFormField

Tags: flutter, validation, textfield, conditional-operator, textformfield

I have a textformfield which validates min length to be at least 3 characters. Later on, I'll validate with backend that the username is unique.

But currently, I'm having trouble showing 2 error text for 2 errors. Namely, one for min length ( "Please enter at least 3 characters for your username") and one for non-unique username ('Your username is popular, please try another one.')

Questions:

- How to make the suffix icon appear only when at least 1 character is typed? instead of by default, I know it's linked to hasMinLengthUnique = false.
- How to show different error text for respective errors?
- And later on, how to put a ternary operator on the navigation to another page based on value hasMinLengthUnique = true.

Bcos right now, whether hasMinLengthUnique = true or false, the navigation doesn't happen.

```
Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _controller,
                    validator: (value) {
                      return (0 < value.length && value.length < 3)
                          ? "Please enter at least 3 characters for your username"
                          : null;
                    },
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        value.length > 2

                            // && username must be unique

                            ? hasMinLengthUnique = true
                            : hasMinLengthUnique = false;
                      });
                    },
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    autofocus: true,
                    maxLength: 15,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      suffix: hasMinLengthUnique
                          ? IconButton(
                              icon:
                                  Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green))
                          : IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.red)),
                      errorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.0),
                      ),
                      errorStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff4aa3f8)),
                      focusedErrorBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                      ),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)),
                        // borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.18,
            ),
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                ),
                child: DelayedDisplay(
                  delay: Duration(seconds: 3),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              onPrimary: Colors.white,
                              primary: Color(0xff3a327f)),
                          child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right, size: 27),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            // if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                            Navigator.push(context, _createRoute());
                            // }
                          })),
                ))
          ]),
        ));
```

[image: Screenshot of Page]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried if else statement in onChanged Value

```
var isValidate; 
onChanged(){
if(1st condition){
setState(){}
}
else if(2nd condition){
setState(){}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code

1. It checks whether a username is greater than 2 or not
2. Then it will check whether your username is popular or not (try typing admin)
3. It will update your `hasMinLengthUnique` accordingly that will update your UI of `IconButton()`
4. It will update your `ElevatedButton()` as well. It becomes disable if `hasMinLengthUnique` is false and become enable if `hasMinLengthUnique` is true.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool hasMinLengthUnique = false;
  var _controller = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey();
  var defUsername = ["admin"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.lightBlue[900],
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Form(
                key: _formKey,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.length < 3) {
                    return "Please enter at least 3 characters for your username";
                  }
                  if (value.contains(defUsername[0])) {
                    return "Username is too popular";
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    if (value.contains(defUsername[0]) ||
                        value.length <= 2) {
                      hasMinLengthUnique = false;
                    } else {
                      hasMinLengthUnique = true;
                    }
                  });
                },
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                autofocus: true,
                maxLength: 15,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding:
                      EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 10),
                  labelText: "Username",
                  suffix: hasMinLengthUnique
                      ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green)
                      : _controller.text.isEmpty
                          ? Icon(null, color: Colors.red)
                          : Icon(Icons.cancel, color: Colors.red),
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.18,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          onPrimary: Colors.white, primary: Color(0xff3a327f)),
                      child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right, size: 27),
                      onPressed: hasMinLengthUnique
                          ? () {
                              print("go to next screen");
                            }
                          : null,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks bro. For the elevated button: why to print 'go to next screen' instead of navigator push to next screen like so :                             Navigator.push(context, _createRoute());

Comment: Yes, it was just a placeholder you can navigate to the next page as well. Code working right?

Comment: I see. Yeap it's working, 2 questions Chirag. The button now only appears when hasMinLengthUnique = true and doesn't appear before that. Can it be made to appear even if bool is false, but just unable to navigate to next page.

Comment: 2nd qtn: the textfield changes position when it's on autofocus vs when it has words in it. How do I ensure that it is always in the same position and not shifting position (altho it's just slightly lowered) when user is typing?

Comment: The Elevatedbutton will be visible but clickable when hasMinLengthUnique is false.

Comment: And your textField is changing its layout because of your error style. Like when the error occurred you are setting some border and other things make it constant for the text field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232678/discussion-between-chirag-bargoojar-and-vegetasaiyan).